# How to programmatically trigger validation of EMF model?

Tags: java, validation, eclipse-emf, .emf

In an editor created with EMF, one can validate a model by right-clicking on any modeled element and choosing "Validate" from the context menu. I want to call this functionality programmatically. My use case is that I want to validate the model when the user attempts to open a wizard. Based on the validation outcome, the wizard will either open (validation succeeded) or the found errors will be displayed.

Does anyone know how to achieve this programmatically?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to trigger the validation thanks to org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.Diagnostician (call `Diagnostician.INSTANCE.validate(...)`). You can have a look at [its javadoc](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.7.0/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/util/Diagnostician.html).

Comment: Hi Stephane, thanks for the quick response. I am still a little puzzled about what eObject to pass the validate method to validate the overall model?

Comment: Hi, you can give it the root(s) of your model.